# Can the python interpreter fail on redeclared functions?

Tags: python, compiler-errors, global-variables

While working on a large enough python file, I have accidentally redefined a function in the global scope.  I would appreciate it if the python interpreter could warn me in those cases.

Imagine you start with this code (version 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

... lots of code ...    

def foo(version):
  if version == 1:
    return "Correct"
  return "Oops!"

... lots more code ...

print foo(1)
```

Which works properly:

```
Correct
```

And then you want to change some things, and call it version 2.  You rewrite the foo function, but you either don't realize the old one existed, or you forget to delete it.  You end up with this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def foo(version):
  if version == 2:
    return "Correct"
  return "Oops!"

... lots of code ...    

def foo(version):
  if version == 1:
    return "Correct"
  return "Oops!"

... lots more code ...

print foo(2)
```

Which doesn't work so well:

```
Oops!
```

I know python allows code like this:

```
def monkey():
  return "patching"
monkey = "is"
def monkey():
  return {"really": "fun"}
```

But it seems like using "def" that way is poor practice.

Is there any way I can get this sort of behavior:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python --def-strict
def foo():
  pass
def foo():
  pass
```

Results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ..., line 3, in <module>
NameError: name 'foo' is already defined
```

Comment: Make sure to keep a clear line between what *does* happen and some hypothetical approach that is *desired*. This makes it seem like there is a "--def-strict" and related error exception, which there is not.

Comment: I think the clean way to address this is by splitting your problem into small to moderately-sized modules. Keeping the modules small will make the problem less likely to happen and much easier to detect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a decorator, which can compare the name of the function and maybe store it in a dictionary. And if the key already exists, you can throw an exception from the decorator! Decorate all your functions with this decorator during development. You can then get rid of the decoration after all your testing is done!

Something like

```
#import sys

if sys.argv[1] == "--def-strict":
    def duplicateFinder(f):
        if globals().has_key(f.__name__):
            raise AttributeError, "This module already has a function %s defined" % f.__name__
        return f
else:
    def duplicateFinder(f):
        return f

@duplicateFinder
def myFunction():
    print "Hello World!"

@duplicateFinder
def myFunction():
    print "Hello World Again!!!"
```

This should throw an error when run with "python --def-strict scriptname".

EDIT: Adding your hypothetical --def-strict! Also, there is no need to keep a separate __functionNames dictionary. The globals() dictionary is good enough. So editing it to reflect the same!

Comment: Now won't this fail when run with any other argument passed to Python (like python -i --def-strict scriptname). I guess doing "--def-strict" in sys.argv would work, though.

Comment: Yup. It would, the condition for that would be --def-strict should always be the first argument! But overall I guess a variable like `DEBUG = True` would be better. Just change the value at the top of the script!

Comment: Actually, I ran into this issue while integrating with PLY, and it somehow managed to generate a warning concerning the redefinition (which I lost amidst the 6000+ line output file).  Therefore it is possible to do without decorators.  Too bad you can't do it at a language level though.

Comment: I don't think this is quite right - the globals() function returns the globals in scope in the module where the code is defined (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals), so if your decorator is in a different module from your decorated function this won't work. The code should be: `if func.__name__ in func.__globals__:`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there's a flag for the Python interpreter that could help you there, but you could use a static code analysis tool like pyflakes, which would warn you about the redefinition (at least in some cases).